# I am getting this error : No overload for method Init takes two arguments. Please

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j00Lc.jpg)

i am getting this error while configuring plugins in my mainActivity class.

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Getting-started#android

Comment: Please post the error in a formatted code block text, this will make it easier for the community to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error represents Rg plugin pop up Init method doesn't take two arguments while you are giving two arguments.Remove second argument in rg plugin Init method.

Replace below code and try it.

Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this);